# Magento 1.8 - Need to Display Category Description to Category Pages

Tags: magento, categories

I'm a Magento nube and am having difficulty getting the category description to display.

I've included the code below and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
<div class="category-description std">![enter image description here][1]
    <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[image]

Comment: Your above code seem correct, did you try to do a reindex and clear cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try if you have not category instance.

```
<?php echo Mage::registry('current_category')->getDescription()?>
```